# PreparedStatement: Missing expression on single quote (ORA-00936)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, ojdbc

I am querying an Oracle database like this:

```java
try (Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_string = ?")) {
    p.setString(1, input);

    try (ResultSet r = p.executeQuery()) {
        // handle ResultSet
    }
}
```

And the `input` string is received from the user. This call is working for normal input strings, like:

```
hello world
special: characters 0_2 (ftlo) -
```

But failing for an input string like this:

```
7-8 l/o y-S '
```

(note the dashes, forward slash, and single quote at the end)

I was assuming it had to do with the single quote, but I was under the impression that `PreparedStatement` takes care of all of the escaping for you. Has anyone seen issues like this, or knows more about character escaping in the oracle JDBC drivers?

I am using:

- Java: 1.8.0_181
- Jboss: EAP 6.4.7.GA
- JDBC: ojdbc6 version 11.2.0.3.0
- Database: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Stacktrace:

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
... <my classes>
```

Comment: Compile errors: 1) `The method openConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource` 2) `The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually turned out that I was getting an error for a different piece of code than I thought. My ResultSetHandler is doing some additional cleanup logic after the main query is finished, and that was throwing the SQLException (missing expression). Due to the implementation of the apache DButils and JDBC libraries, the error was swallowed and not printed in a helpful way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem due single quote, because in Oracle the last must be repeated twice to be enterpreted as single quote or whole string must be included in q'{...}' construct where ... is a given string.

Comment: Usually 1PreparedStatement.setString()` takes care of it. At least that is one of the purposes of `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. Added file `ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3).

Ran following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code against 12.1.0.2 server *(values to `getConnection` has of course been masked)*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test("hello world");
    test("special: characters 0_2 (ftlo) -");
    test("7-8 l/o y-S '");
    test("X");
}
private static void test(String input) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(input);
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:XXX", "XXX", "XXX")) {
        String sql = "select DUMMY from DUAL where DUMMY = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            stmt.setString(1, input);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + rs.getString("DUMMY"));
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("  " + count + " rows");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
hello world
  0 rows
special: characters 0_2 (ftlo) -
  0 rows
7-8 l/o y-S '
  0 rows
X
  X
  1 rows
```

Comment: I wouldn't really consider this a valid test, though, because that SELECT statement seems to be returning 0 rows for any string that isn't "X".

Comment: @JeffBrower Whether query actually returns data is besides the point. The error in the question is a SQL **Syntax** Error, which means it's a issue with *parsing* the SQL statement, not executing it.